# Fast way to parse a Long date into Month-Day-Year String

Tags: java, gwt

How do you parse a Long date like: `1366222239935` into a String of space-separated `Month-Day-Year`? Like into `"Apr 18 2013"`

Passing it on a `java.util.Date` and to a `String` will give a String of date which contains so many info that I don't need for rendering in my GWT application.

Need to do this style since I will be passing the result into 3 `<span>` elements; so actually the space-separated date will be split into parts:

- Month
- Day
- Year

Comment: Is that a long number in milliseconds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As gwt won't support  `SimpleDateFormat`

instead use Gwt [**DateTimeFormat**](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
DateTimeFormat f = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

String datestring =f.format(dateGeneratedbyLong);
```

And make sure the `DateTimeFormat` import also which you can use both `client` and `server` side .

There is another class with same name but package is different which is client(restricts you to use on client side only )

Answer (score 0):

That `Long` number is simply the number of milliseconds since the JavaScript epoch (1/1/1970 at midnight, UTC time). So, instead of parsing it, use the constructor for the `Date` object:

```
  var myDate = new Date(1366222239935);
  alert(myDate);
```

That will show "Wed Apr 17 2013 11:10:39 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)". I am in PST, but it will default to whatever timezone you have in your locale settings.

Inside a GWT app in Java, simply do:

```
     Date date=new Date(1366222239935);
```

Then you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to render it as "dd/MM/yy".

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: You are correct Diego but Unfortunately gwt doesnt support simpledateformat.

Answer (score 0):

try to use SimpleDataFormat check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html>

`SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");`

`String dateAsString = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());`

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a `Date` and then manually build your `String` like this.-

```
Date date = new Date(timeInMils);
String res = date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + 
             date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + 
             date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
    Date d = new Date();

    d.setTime(1366222239935l);

    System.out.println(d);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy");

    try {
        System.out.println(sdf.format((d)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, here is the output Wed Apr 17 14:10:39 EDT 2013
April 17 2013

Answer (score 0):

```
    long diff = 1366222239935l;

    Date date = new Date(diff);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```